# importar multiples models en otro model Django 2.X

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-forms

Estoy intentando crear un formulario para mi proyecto con Django 2.0, con Python 3.6.4 en Windows 10, pero al momento de usar una referencia de algunos models de otra app me dice que no existe o que no esta definido, en una pregunta parecida decía que era necesario una referencia al inicio usando models. (models.Empleado) pero si hago esto me dice el siguiente error:

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x05F7F0C0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\FERNAN~1\Envs\MYPROJ~1\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\FERNAN~1\Envs\MYPROJ~1\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 113, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "C:\Users\FERNAN~1\Envs\MYPROJ~1\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 248, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "C:\Users\FERNAN~1\Envs\MYPROJ~1\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 327, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "C:\Users\FERNAN~1\Envs\MYPROJ~1\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\FERNAN~1\Envs\MYPROJ~1\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\FERNAN~1\Envs\MYPROJ~1\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 112, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "C:\Users\FERNAN~1\Envs\MYPROJ~1\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 198, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\Users\FERNAN~1\Envs\MYPROJ~1\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\Fernando Leon\dev\django\oasiSystem\apps\captura\models.py", line 12, in <module>
    class Turno(models.Model):
  File "C:\Users\Fernando Leon\dev\django\oasiSystem\apps\captura\models.py", line 16, in Turno
    no_parte = models.ForeignKey(models.NumParte, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
AttributeError: module 'django.db.models' has no attribute 'NumParte'
```

y si retiro esa referencia el error que me dice es el siguiente:

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x068DF0C0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\FERNAN~1\Envs\MYPROJ~1\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\FERNAN~1\Envs\MYPROJ~1\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 113, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "C:\Users\FERNAN~1\Envs\MYPROJ~1\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 248, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "C:\Users\FERNAN~1\Envs\MYPROJ~1\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 327, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "C:\Users\FERNAN~1\Envs\MYPROJ~1\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\FERNAN~1\Envs\MYPROJ~1\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\FERNAN~1\Envs\MYPROJ~1\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 112, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "C:\Users\FERNAN~1\Envs\MYPROJ~1\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 198, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\Users\FERNAN~1\Envs\MYPROJ~1\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\Fernando Leon\dev\django\oasiSystem\apps\captura\models.py", line 12, in <module>
    class Turno(models.Model):
  File "C:\Users\Fernando Leon\dev\django\oasiSystem\apps\captura\models.py", line 16, in Turno
    no_parte = models.ForeignKey(NumParte, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
NameError: name 'NumParte' is not defined
```

mi código del model.py es el siguiente:

```
from django.db import models
from django.forms import ModelForm

from .models import *

# Create your models here.
class TipoTurno(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    created_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    updated_at = models.DateField(auto_now=True)

class Turno(models.Model):
    comentario = models.CharField(max_length=140, null=True)
    turno = models.ForeignKey(TipoTurno, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    fecha_realizado = models.DateField(null=True)
    no_parte = models.ForeignKey(NumParte, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    inspector = models.ForeignKey(Empleado, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    updated_at = models.DateField(auto_now=True)

class Asistencia(models.Model):
    empleado = models.ForeignKey(Empleado, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    comentarios = models.CharField(max_length=140, null=True)
    fecha_inicio = models.DateField()
    fecha_fin = models.DateField()
    hora_inicio = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    hora_fin = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    total_hrs_trabajadas = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    turno = models.ForeignKey(Turno, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    most_analisis = models.ForeignKey(MostrarAnalisis, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    updated_at = models.DateField(auto_now=True)

class TipoValor(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    created_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    updated_at = models.DateField(auto_now=True)

class Campo(models.Model):
    # Falta anotar lo de la tabla de piece_items
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    descripcion = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    tipo = models.ForeignKey(TipoValor, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    requerido = models.ForeignKey(Requerido, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    estatus = models.ForeignKey(Estatus, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    editable = models.ForeignKey(EsEditable, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    updated_at = models.DateField(auto_now=True)

class CapturaCampo(models.Model):
    valor = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    campo = models.ForeignKey(Campo, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    fecha = models.DateField(null=False)
    captura = models.ForeignKey(Captura, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    most_analisis = models.ForeignKey(MostrarAnalisis, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE) 
    created_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    updated_at = models.DateField(auto_now=True)

class Defecto(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    descripcion = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    estatus = models.ForeignKey(Estatus, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    updated_at = models.DateField(auto_now=True)

class CapturaDefecto(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    valor = models.IntegerField()
    defecto = models.ForeignKey(Defecto, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    fecha = models.DateField()
    captura = models.ForeignKey(Captura, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    most_analisis = models.ForeignKey(MostrarAnalisis, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    updated_at = models.DateField(auto_now=True)

class Captura (models.Model):
    cotizacion = models.ForeignKey(Cotizacion, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    fecha = models.DateField()
    turno = models.ForeignKey(Turno, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    usuario = models.ForeignKey(Usuario, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    updated_at = models.DateField(auto_now=True)

class TipoTurnoForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = TipoTurno
        fields = ('nombre',)

class TurnoForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Turno
        fields = (
            'comentario',
            'turno',
            'fecha_realizado',
            'no_parte',
            'inspector',
        )

class AsistenciaForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Asistencia
        fields = (
            'empleado',
            'comentarios',
            'fecha_inicio',
            'fecha_fin',
            'hora_inicio',
            'hora_fin',
            'total_hrs_trabajadas',
            'turno',
            'most_analisis',
        )

class TipoValorForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = TipoValor
        fields = ('nomrbre',)

class CampoForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Campo
        fields = (
            'nombre',
            'descripcion',
            'tipo',
            'requerido',
            'estatus',
            'editable',
        )

class CapturaCampoForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CapturaCampo
        fields = (
            'valor',
            'campo',
            'fecha',
            'captura',
            'most_analisis',
        )

class DefectoForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Defecto
        fields = (
            'nombre',
            'descripcion',
            'estatus',
        )

class CapturaDefectoForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CapturaDefecto
        fields = (
            'nombre',
            'valor',
            'defecto',
            'fecha',
            'captura',
            'most_analisis',
        )

class CapturaForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Captura
        fields = (
            'cotizacion',
            'fecha',
            'turno',
            'usuario',
        )
```

el código donde tengo agregado el model 'NumParte' es el siguiente:

```
from django.db import models
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import * 

# Create your models here.
class Visible(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    created_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    updated_at = models.DateField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre

class Estatus(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    created_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    updated_at = models.DateField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre

class EsEditable(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    created_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    updated_at = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre

class Requerido(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    created_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    updated_at = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre

class MostrarAnalisis(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    created_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    updated_at = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre

class MostrarCotizacion(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    created_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    updated_at = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre

class Archivada(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    created_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    updated_at = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre

class NumParte(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    cont = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    updated_at = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre

class TipoRate(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    created_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    updated_at = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre

class Idioma(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    created_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    updated_at = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre

class Moneda(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    created_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    updated_at = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre

class Impuesto(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    valor = models.DecimalField(null=False,max_digits=2,decimal_places=2)
    #procedencia = models.ForeignKey
    activo = models.ForeignKey(Estatus, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    updated_at = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre

class TipoOperacion(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    created_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    updated_at = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre

class Correo(models.Model):
    # persona = models.ManyToManyField(Empleado, db_table="contact-mail")
    correo = models.CharField(max_length=120) 
    created_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    updated_at = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.correo

class Telefono(models.Model):
    # persona = models.ManyToManyField(Empleado, db_table="contact-tel")
    telefono = models.IntegerField()
    extencion = models.IntegerField(default="0", null=True)
    created_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    updated_at = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    def get_fullphone():
        return self.telefono + ' ext. ' + self.extencion

    def __str__(self):
        return get_fullphone

class ConceptoDeCobro(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    created_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    updated_at = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre

class TipoDeTrabajo(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    created_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    updated_at = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre

class TipoMoneda(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    nombre_corto = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    created_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    updated_at = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre

class TipoTurno(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    horario = models.CharField(max_length=45, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    updated_at = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    def get_fullname():
        return self.nombre + ' ' + self.horario

    def __str__(self):
        return get_fullname()

class Parametro(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=512)
    created_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    updated_at = models.DateField(auto_now=True)

class DetalleTrabajo(models.Model):
    detalle = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    created_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    updated_at = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    def __str__(self):
        self.detalle

class VisibleForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Visible
        fields = ('nombre',)

class EstatusForm(Modelform):
    class Meta:
        model = Estatus
        fields = ('nombre',)

class EsEditableForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = EsEditable
        fields = ('nombre',)

class RequeridoForm(Modelform):
    class Meta:
        model = Requerido
        fields = ('nombre',)

class MostrarAnalisisForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MostrarAnalisis
        fiels = ('nombre',)

class MostrarCotizacionForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MostrarCotizacion
        fields = ('nombre',)

class ArchivadaForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Archivada
        fields = ('Archivada',)

class NumParteForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = NumParte
        fields = ('nombre',)

class TipoRateForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = TipoRate
        fields = ('nombre',)

class IdiomaForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Idioma
        fields = ('nombre',)

class MonedaForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Moneda
        fields = ('nombre',)

class ImpuestoForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Impuesto
        fields = ('nombre',)

class TipoOperacionForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = TipoOperacion
        fields = ('nombre',)

class Correoform(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Correo
        fields = ('nombre',)

class TelefonoForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Telefono
        fields = ('telefono', 'extension',)

class ConceptoDeCobroForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ConceptoDeCobro
        fields = ('nombre')

class TipoMonedaForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = TipoMoneda
        fields = ('nombre',)

class TipoDeTrabajoForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = TipoDeTrabajo
        fields = ('nombre',)

class TipoTurnoForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = TipoTurno
        fields = ('nombre', 'horario',)

class DetalleTrabajoForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = DetalleTrabajo
        fields = ('nombre',)

class ParametroForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Parametro
        Fields = ('nombre',)
```

Espero que alguien pueda ayudarme se los agradecería mucho, espero puedan ver mi error que yo no puedo detectar.
Gracias de ante mano

Comment: para agregar un model es: from aplicacion.models import MiModel, ejemplo from empleados.models import empleados

Comment: ya intente tambien de ese modo, la ruta para agregar mi model es `from apps.empleado.model import Empleado` pero al agregar distintos modelos (dos o mas) siempre sucede el mismo error con todos mis modelos, anteriormente pude solucionarlo con `campo = models.ForeignkeyField('empleado.Empleado')` pero necesito que funcione correctamente por que en lso queryset no me funciona de la misma forma

Comment: olvide mencionar que con las Foreignkeys anteriores todo funciona bien hasta que llega a esa que se llama NumParte, en uno o mas modelos solo me detecta la primer o segunda referencia de modelo y el resto de los casos ya los detecta como `"name 'NumParte' is not definied"`

Comment: mira esto https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#a-full-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A la hora de importar un modelo u otra cosa mediante `.` estás queriendo decir que ese fichero se encuentra local dentro de la misma app, me explico mejor. Si un proyecto Django está compuesto por 2 o más apps ejemplo: RecusrosHumanos, Inventario y una vez dentro del views.py que pertenece a RecursosHumanos quieres importar todos los modelos de él mismo, puedes declarar

```
from .models import *
```

de esta forma importas todos los modelos pertenecientes a es App que se encuentran en models.py dentro de su propio Directorio. Lo otro es que necesites en el views.py de RecursosHumanos utilizar uno o varios modelos de la App Inventario, entonces si deberías verificar que en tu settings.py global en INSTALLED_APPS se encuentre la App que necesitas utilizar, ese es el primer paso ejemplo:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'recusroshumanos',
    'inventario',
    'django.contrib.admin'
]
```

una vez definida puedes, en cualquier parte de la App RecursosHumanos importar lo que necesites de la App Inventario. ejemplo:

RecusrosHumanos/views.py

```
from inventario.models import *
```

de esta forma tienes acceso desde RecusrosHumanos a todos los modelos definidos en el models.py dentro de la App Inventario. tambien cabe destacar que esta filosofía no solo es aplicable en el caso de los modelos,puedes utilizarlo para importar lo que necesites reutilizar